# Is there any firefox addon which logs keystrokes made in firefox browser?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, keylogger

Is there any firefox addon which logs keystrokes made in firefox browser?.. If so what is it?

Comment: That's a bit sketchy...

Comment: that is really sketchy.  just make your keylogger in c++ like everyone else.

Comment: There's lots of good malware that will do that... they'll posted them to a web server for easy pick up too! <grin>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's only one, and it hasn't been updated to run with FF higher than 3.0.*

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/13713

Alternatively, you can use a macro add-on, like [iMacros](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3863)

Answer (score 0):

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gtfo-sync/

is modern and works well.  It is set up to log over mongolab db so you have to create a free account with them.  takes a couple minuts pretty easy. there is a help page.

In the end you can view those logs remotely on any browser through the extension if you have it configured with the same db info. you could also just use curl.

Also open source

https://github.com/thebleedingegg/gtfo-sync

and sketch with a capital S

`posession may be nine tenths, but it only takes one persone to touch you` -Sun Tzu